# Unable to create replication source in Azure

Tags: azure

I create a VM in West US by mistake. Now I want to migrate it to another location. The guide I am using is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/tutorial-migrate-azure-to-azure

It involves several steps:

1. Create a vault
2. Select the source
3. Enable replication for Azure VMs
4. Run a failover

Now I am stuck at the second stage - I am just unable to select the source - it does not show any resource group!

I am very new to Azure and have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a resource group in West US?

Comment: Nope, Canada East. I get your point. Let me check. It is really confusing that creating a VM in US West with a resource group in Canada East is allowed, but replication source is not. Unintuitive, at first glance.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Please, arrange your comment as an answer and I will credit you. Also, if you could explain why it is allowed to create a VM in West US with resource group in Canada East, but not a replication source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have at least one resource group in the source VM location.

Comment: Is there an explanation online why is it OK to create VM in location X with resource group in location Y, but it is not OK for other resources, like replication source?